# EF Core get new ID without POCO

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My goal is to get ID before creating instance of my entity. I am not considering to use GUID. Essentially I would like to create an empty row in database then get id for this row so that I can assign it to my entity.

Is it possible to do that with Entity Framework 7, if yes - how?

I have to obtain ID beforehand because my entity has constructor with some rules and I do not want to persist that model just yest. I am planing to use separate service which will get me IDs. Some factory that will assemble all together to create entity instance.

Addendum:
Entities will raise events. Listeners will react to them and probably reference entity with its ID. I think it is only reasonable that everything will be persisted in same transaction so ID before storing is a must.

Comment: By the time you create a row in your database, the entity does exist, so I don’t know why you don’t just use the normal entity class for it. Otherwise, if you want to eventually move the ID generation out of the database, then just do that and create a service that provides you with an id. Just note that this needs to be synchronized in case you request two ids at the same time.

Comment: This is smelly. You shouldn't have any business logic that depends on arbitrary primary key values. If your business rules can't wait until there is an assigned key (a *surrogate* key!), there must be something wrong. How would you guarantee that the key is still available after the rules have used it and the entity is finally stored?

Comment: Rules does not depend on ID. ID is needed for referencing entity.

Comment: By the time you create a row in your database, the entity does exist, so I don’t know why you don’t just use the normal entity class for it. - This is not true.

Comment: *ID is needed for referencing entity* Then use a temporary id that you obtain from some local id generator. The actual id value will be overwritten when the new entity is saved.